# Java streams: return results to custom object

Tags: java, java-stream

I have a piece of code that has list of objects as follows.

```
List<PivotMapEgModel> pivotMapList = List.of(new PivotMapEgModel(1L, "1"), new PivotMapEgModel(1L, "2"), new PivotMapEgModel(1L, "3"), new PivotMapEgModel(2L, "5"));
```

It is guaranteed that there will always be a maximum of 3 codes per value.

I have a class that looks like this:

```
@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
class ResultSet {
    long value;
    String code_1;
    String code_2;
    String code_3;
}
```

I am currently doing the stream operation in this way:

```
pivotMapList.stream().collect(Collectors.groupingBy(PivotMapEgModel::getValue, Collectors.mapping(PivotMapEgModel::getCode, Collectors.toList())))
```

This is producing the output in the following way: `{1=[1, 2, 3], 2=[5]}`

I need to perform stream operations on the pivotMapList to get the output to show in `List<ResultSet>` as follows:

```
[{value=1, code_1=1, code_2=2, code_3=3},
 {value=2, code_1=1, code_2=null, code_3=null}]
```

I am not sure how I can get `List<ResultSet>` from stream operations

Any help to achieve the desired output would be greatly appreciated! Thank you

Comment: Are you guaranteed to always have at most 3 codes for 1 value? If not, what happens if you get more than 3, `1=[1, 2, 3, 4]` for example?

Comment: It is guaranteed that there will always be a maximum of 3 codes.

Comment: If you had to do it without streams, what would you do? Have you looked at the methods available in [Collector](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collector.html)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have already mapped value to its codes. You can just continue by streaming the entry set of the resulting map and [map](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#map-java.util.function.Function-) entries to `ResultSet`.

```
List<ResultSet> result = pivotMapList.stream()
            .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(PivotMapEgModel::getValue, Collectors.mapping(PivotMapEgModel::getCode, Collectors.toList())))
            .entrySet()
            .stream()
            .map(entry -> new ResultSet(entry.getKey(), getCode(entry.getValue(), 0), getCode(entry.getValue(), 1), getCode(entry.getValue(), 2)))
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

`getCode()` is simple method taking care not to get exception when retrieving values from the list.

```
private static String getCode(List<String> codes, int index) {
  if (index >= codes.size()) {
    return null;
  }
  return codes.get(index);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is one way.

```
class ResultSet {

    long value;
    String code_1;
    String code_2;
    String code_3;

    public ResultSet(long value, String code_1,String code_2, String code_3) {
        this.value = value;
        this.code_1 = code_1;
        this.code_2 = code_2;
        this.code_3 = code_3;
    }
    
    public String toString() {
        return "{%d, %s, %s, %s}".formatted(value, code_1, code_2, code_3);
    }
}
```

Use your existing map to build the list.  Stream the entrySet of the map and use `map` to instantiate a `ResultSet` instance.  The forloop will fill the list with nulls if it isn't fully populated.

```
List<ResultSet> resultSet = map.entrySet().stream()
        .<ResultSet>map(ent-> {
            List<String> lst = ent.getValue();
            for( int i = lst.size(); i < 3; i++) {
                lst.add(null);
            }
            return new ResultSet(ent.getKey(), lst.get(0),
                    lst.get(1), lst.get(2));
        }).toList();


resultSet.forEach(System.out::println);
```

prints

```
{1, 1, 2, 3}
{2, 5, null, null}
```

Note that you could simply stream the existing `entrySet` from the original map to combine the process, returning the desired `List<ResultSet>`